# Format SQL form output

Tags: sql, forms

This is my form page:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Log</title>
</head>
<h1> Log </h1>
<form method="get" action="getlog2.php"> 
<table width="300" border="0">
  <tr>
<td> Forte ID:</td>
<td><select id="ForteID" name="ForteID">                    
                <option value="'nc4682'">nc4682</option>
                <option value="'bs1441'">bs1441</option>
                <option value="'sp3212'">sp3212</option>                 
    </select></td>
  </tr>
</table>

 <input type="submit" name="getLog" value="Get Log"><input type="button" value="Form" onClick="window.location.href='index.php';">
 </form> 

</head>
```

This code here is what I have for my form when I click the button "Get Log".

```
<?php
/*print_r($_POST);*/
$serverName = 'SRB-Nick_Desktop\SQLEXPRESS';
$connectionInfo = array('Database'=>'cslogs', 'UID'=>'cslogslogin', 'PWD'=>'123456','ReturnDatesAsStrings'=>true,);
$connection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

$query = 'SELECT ForteID, Disposition, appNumber, Finance_Num, Num_Payments, ACH_CC, Notes, Date from cslogs.dbo.logs WHERE ForteID = ' . $_GET['ForteID'];

$result = sqlsrv_query($connection,$query);
/*echo $_GET['ForteID'];*/
if (!$result)

{
/*echo $query;*/
$message = 'ERROR: ' . sqlsrv_errors();
return $message;
}
else
{ 
$i = 0;
echo '<html><body><table><tr>';
while ($i < sqlsrv_num_rows($result))
{
    $meta = sqlsrv_fetch($result, $i);
    echo '<td>' . $meta->name . '</td>';
    $i = $i + 1;
}
echo '</tr>';

while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ))
{
    $count = count($row);
    $y = 0;
    echo '<tr>';
    while ($y < $count)
    {
        $c_row = current($row);
        echo '<td>' . $c_row . '</td>';
        next($row);
        $y = $y + 1;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt ($result);

echo '</table></body></html>';
}
sqlsrv_close( $connection);
?>
```

It then goes to a page where this is output:

```
bs1441  LOC asldjfasdf  srb-000001  1   cc  collected payment   2012-11-07
```

I want to format the output with borders and headers, is that possible?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, it's possible. you're in control of the output, after all.

Comment: Everywhere you echo text you can add classes to the table/tags, and then design that table either w/ inline css or an additional css file. I don't think you understand what your doing as its right there in front of you.